# Allow bell for only one terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am using mcabber via ssh, and using mcabber bell for sound of incoming message. In windows I used kitty it allows you to set audio file for terminal bell. In linux I still want to hear mcabber incomming messages.

Do you know a terminal emulator that allows you to set audio file for bell or do you know how to activate system bell but just for 1 terminal window?

Please do not advise solutions like using mcabber api and sockets to transfer event to client pc. I want to use ssh bell in this solution, like it was working on windows.

Answer (score 0):

To activate the speaker driver that produce beeps only for current session use the following command in terminal:

```
 sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

To disable it again, run:

```
sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
```

Comment: I need audio bell (not speaker) only for one window, not session.